# Spark SQL grouping: Add to group by or wrap in first() if you don't care which value you get.;

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark, udf

I have a query in Spark SQL like

```
select count(ts), truncToHour(ts)
from myTable
group by truncToHour(ts).
```

Where `ts` is of timestamp type, `truncToHour` is a UDF that truncates the timestamp to hour. This query does not work. If I try,

```
select count(ts), ts from myTable group by truncToHour(ts)
```

I got `expression 'ts' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() if you don't care which value you get.;`, but `first()` is not defined if I do:

```
select count(ts), first(ts) from myTable group by truncToHour(ts)
```

Anyway to get what I wanted without using a subquery? Also, why does it say "wrap in first()" but the `first()` is not defined?

Answer (score 4):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9210

Seems the actual function is first_value.

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution:

```
SELECT max(truncHour(ts)), COUNT(ts) FROM myTable GROUP BY truncHour(ts)
```

or

```
SELECT truncHour(max(ts)), count(ts) FROM myTable GROUP BY truncHour(ts)
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems better but requires nesting

```
select truncHrTs, count(ts)
from(
select ts, truncToHour(ts) AS truncHrTs
from myTable
)
group by truncHrTs
```